# SSH and VNC insanely slow on RPi 2

Tags: ssh, connection, vnc, internet

I have a Raspi 2. I just installed Raspbian on it but the SSH session is insanely slow. I type something in the terminal, on my laptop and it appears in 10 seconds. I installed X11VNC and ran it through Remmina. It is unusable, and X11 says:

```
24/07/2016 11:49:22 link_rate: LR_BROADBAND - 6 ms, 62 KB/s
24/07/2016 11:49:22 client useCopyRect: 192.168.0.14 -1
24/07/2016 11:49:23 client_set_net: 192.168.0.14  0.0576
24/07/2016 11:49:23 created   xdamage object: 0x1400040
24/07/2016 11:49:23 copy_tiles: allocating first_line at size 61
24/07/2016 11:49:31 created selwin: 0x1400041
24/07/2016 11:49:31 called initialize_xfixes()
24/07/2016 11:49:38 increased wireframe timeouts for slow network connection.
```

62 kb/s ?? I am literally next to the router. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is it a wifi connection? Can you run `iwlist wlan0 scan` or get an app to show the APs nearby. Are there some using the same channel? Are you using the channel used by mircowaves?

Comment: Probably not an explanation for your problem, but note that being "literally next to the router" does not guarantee you a good/better connection if the WLAN is busy; in this case all nodes must compete, which may cause a slowdown, and if it does, proximity is not a significant advantage.   I.e., if there are a bunch of other devices streaming over wifi at the same time it will hurt your connection speed.  But it should still not be that much unless "a bunch" is into the dozens, I think.

Comment: @ott   wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connecting it through ethernet. The most likely reason for this happening is that your antenna on the dongle is too small, so even when it is close to a router, it is slow.

Comment: Problem is, I've used this dongle for about a year now. It used to be much much faster.

Comment: @Bixqu Maybe there is interference?

Comment: Possible, but there's no way I can check that.

Comment: @Bixqu Then I do not know why this is happening, sorry

Comment: I got an ethernet cable and now it's lightning fast, both SSH in the terminal and VNC through x11vnc. It was the wifi dongle.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Xming` instead. You can download it from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/files/latest/download)

Also download `Xming Fonts`. Here is the download [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/files/Xming-fonts/7.5.0.93/Xming-fonts-7-5-0-93-setup.exe/download)

If you don't know `Xming`, you can watch this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwnTKnrYJtM) on how to setup on your windows desktop.

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention, I am using Ubuntu Linux not Windows.

Comment: @Bixqu Then my answer is incompatible. Sorry for that, but will try to figure out something else.

Comment: @Bixqu This documentation might help you to choose another Desktop Viewer [doc link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Clients)

Answer (score 1):

Install Tight VNC Server, It's good for me.

1. `sudo apt-get install tightvncserver`.
2. Go to root user and `vncserver`.
3. `vncpasswd`.